# CSS: positioning issue

Tags: css

So i have a slideshow, here's the css to start with:

```
#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height:300px;
    width: 477px;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: 20px;

}

#slideshow IMG {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
    opacity:0.0;
}

#slideshow IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
    opacity:1.0;
}

#slideshow IMG.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}
```

And then i have a box, that i want to be on top of the slideshow.. but right now its under the slideshow, even if its position absolute..

```
#regForm {
position: absolute;
top: 120px;
left: 500px;
background: #000;
color: #FFF;
width: 500px;
height: 240px;
border: 6px solid #18110c;
text-align: center;
margin: 40px;
padding: 1px;
  opacity: 0.75;
  -moz-opacity: 0.75; /* older Gecko-based browsers */
  filter:alpha(opacity=75); /* For IE6&7 */

}
```

How should i positioning it right so the div box comes on top of the slideshow and not under?

Comment: What does your HTML structure look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `z-index:11;` to the `#regForm` style declaration.